# yii - difference between radioButtonList and activeRadioButtonList

Tags: yii

in the yii framework

what is the difference between radioButtonList and activeRadioButtonList?

Answer (score 15):

In Yii there is a "regular" and "active" version of (almost?) every CHtml form field helper/widget. With the "active" version you pass in the ActiveRecord Model and the Attribute you want to make a form field for. This ties the ActiveRecord model more closely to the form field which helps with a few things like:

1. applying the model->attribute's validation rules (especially ajax validation)
2. building the proper form $_POST structure for model->attribute assignments
3. getting the proper field label
4. etc

Use *activeRadioButtonList* if you are building a form for an ActiveRecord model, and use *radioButtonList* if you are building a regular form (for a CFormModel model).

Read more about the both versions of the radioButtonList helper here:

1. http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/CHtml#activeRadioButtonList-detail
2. http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/CHtml#radioButtonList-detail

Answer (score 3):

radioButtonList not related to model
activeRadioButtonList related to model